# Play local video on a P5.js script

Tags: processing, p5.js

I know to use a video that is already on the server.
My question is if using a remote server can I manage(play, stop, get info, get audiotrack) a video that is on my local drive without uploading it?

I would like to add a createFileInput() and work with it.

Is that possible?
Thanks

Comment: browser security won't allow you to (and it's a good thing): you don't want any remote server having access to your local drive. you can run a local webser though and display that video locally. if you need to play the video from the remote server you would need to upload that video.

Comment: Not sure @GeorgeProfenza, as if a dialog box is used to select a file, the user can choose it to his needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the clarification in the comment.

You can have create a video element at runtime based on what the users uploads, all on the client side.

Here's a slightly modified version of the [`createFileInput()` p5.js example:](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createFileInput):

```js
let input;
let img;

function setup() {
  input = createFileInput(handleFile);
  input.position(0, 0);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  if (img) {
    image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  }
}

function handleFile(file) {
  print(file);
  if (file.type === 'video') {
    img = createVideo(file.data, '');
    img.loop();
    img.hide();
  } else {
    img = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

You can upload and serve a basic front-end like this on a remote server.
You can then get the info and use an HTTP request to send that from the front-end to the back-end if the server needs it. Additionally, you can easily control playback from the front-end, but if you need to control it from the back-end, for some reason, you need to establish a connection between the two (e.g. WebSocket, Server Sent Events, etc.)